# How to make some controls visible and overlapping a DIV when mouse hovers on it?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am not so pro in CSS and JavaScript. I am working on an article website where users create and edit articles. Currently whenever user wants to delete or edit an article, he clicks some button given below each DIV that represents an article. The code is like this

```
<div id="article"><!-- article data --></div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
            style="height: 26px" Text="Delete" />
```

But what I want is, this delete button must not be visible when page loads. It should only be visible when user hovers mouse over the corresponding div and also it should overlap the div in bottom-right corner of the div. Please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses jQuery to handle a fade in and fade out. I don't know anything about ASP or C# but maybe this will help [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/atomicpages/KVeg2/)! Just hover over the black square in the bottom left corner and you'll see the delete button show up. The jQuery can be seen here:

```
$('.delete input').hide();
$('.delete').hover(
    function() {
        $('.delete input').fadeIn();
    }, function() {
      $('.delete input').fadeOut();
    }
);
```

Comment: its visible when I hover on the `<div class="delete">` and that also only works when I have `border: 1px solid black;` enabled in css. But I want it should be visible when I hover over `<div class="article">` and without the border property set in css. How should I achieve that?

Comment: @ShivaPareek Work with that code that gives you as example and solve it by your self. Do not expect here to programming for you all the details. And after that if you have some issue, come back and ask him.

Comment: Shiva, you don't need the border. If you comment out the CSS the area is "hidden" from view. I would recommend a lesser opacity so an admin can actually see the button. If you want it to be visible as soon as someone enters the `.article` element then just change the jQuery, specifically `$( **'.delete'** ).hover`

Comment: ok thanks @djthoms, this worked for me. Marking as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the button visible by css, it would be something like

```
div:hover input {visibility: visible}
```

That would work with the code that you give. Of course, if you have a more complex page, you should make the rule more specific (asigning a class to the div, probably)